# Client needs a Paypal donation form with recognition wall - use Comments?

Tags: paypal

I've got a site in progress that is a redesign of a Wordpress website, and the client was using a WP plugin that allowed users to make a Paypal donation and leave a comment for the donation "wall of recognition."  I see a few WordPress plugins available with this kind of functionality, but nothing similar for EE.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set this up just using the EE Comments module?  Can I set up a Paypal donate form and somehow send the EE comment with it?  And if the user selects a box for "show my donation amount", pass that donation amount along with the comment form?  Seems plausible in my head, but it's a bit beyond my comfort zone coding-wise, so before I delve into it too much, wondering if anyone else has a better idea of how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a way to do it with the included Simple Commerce and PayPal; otherwise it would be fairly easy to setup with the Charge add-on, although you'd be using Stripe instead of PayPal.